# Installing Ubuntu Server 17.04 and "Install the system" fails

Tags: boot, server, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu Server 17.04 on an external hard drive and the install failed. Here's a picture of the error message:

[image]

I'm installing it from a USB drive on a laptop. I was thinking that perhaps the drive didn't have enough storage space to install it? It's 4GB drive.
I also have a 500GB external hard drive that I partitioned, if I need to install the software on that.

Comment: Did you hashcheck the ISO you downloaded and used to create the install media?

Comment: What's hashcheck? Sorry, I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm installing Ubuntu Server in an attempt to create a cloud storage program

Comment: The standard name is a `hashsum` I think. My answer explains how to check.

Comment: Use CTRL + ALT + F4, it will show the log, you should see what failed last.  Use CTRL + ALT + F1 to go back to the installer.

Comment: Use SHA1 sum to check if the file was fully downloaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of potential issues. I've listed them in order of likelihood:

1. The ISO file is corrupted. Perhaps you downloaded it from the wrong page, perhaps it was corrupted during or after the download. There is a small chance the download server has a corrupted ISO - either through chance, accident or malicious attack.

   To check your ISO file run the following command:

   ```
   sha1sum /path/to/isofile.iso
   ```

   For Ubuntu Server 17.04, it should be `61479ab49395ac7374c1d0e2226267d997653715`. If yours is a different version of Ubuntu (e.g. 32 bit) you can [find the sums here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/zesty/SHA1SUMS).

   If your SHA1 sum doesn't match the advertised one, you've got a corrupted ISO. Redownload it from [the Ubuntu server here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/zesty/).
2. The disk is damaged - physically or in the partitions. Try repartitioning it, if you can't you may need to [wipe the start of the disk](https://askubuntu.com/a/223182/186134).
3. The disk is too small for Ubuntu Server 17.04. It could be that 4GB is simply not enough space - although that seems unlikely - [the Wiki says 1.5GB is enough](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Server_.28CLI.29_Installation).

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: OK... I've checked the size of my drive. It's advertised online as 4GB, but after checking its properties, there was only 1.15GB left over (after the .iso  file was installed). So I guess that's the problem. I've ordered a 32GB flash drive, so let's hope that there's no false advertising!

Comment: I'm going to wait until the 32GB drive arrives (and I test it) to award you the bounty.

Comment: @pagie_ did you check the ISO file you downloaded to ensure it has the right hash?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you have the iso file in the target drive, and that you are not allowing the installer to grab the whole drive.

Comment: @pagie_ which was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly the same installation issue. I used unetbootin app on macOS to create the bootable usb drive as seems to be recommended, trying with both a 4GB and an 8GB drive, but same problem for both. I verified the checksum was of the ISO correct too.

In the end I tried a different way of creating the bootable usb drive [following this guide](http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/05/copy-iso-to-usb-drive-mac-os-x-command/) (which uses `dd` from the terminal instead) using my 8GB drive and Ubuntu 17.04 installed without a problem.

Comment: what does that guide say?

Comment: it uses `dd` from the terminal instead.